# How to go previous activity searchview back button?

Tags: java, android

I have a very simple question. I have implemented searchview in my menu. So the activity starts with expanded searchview. And now when I press back button, the searchview first collapse and goes back to previous activity.

Here's my code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchItem.expandActionView();
    SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_hint));
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setFocusable(true);
    mSearchView.setIconified(false);
    mSearchView.requestFocus();
    mSearchView.setGravity(Gravity.END);
    mSearchView.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    //mSearchView.setLayoutParams(new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Gravity.END));
    //String searchQuery = getIntent().getStringExtra("SEARCH");
    //SearchActivity.this.myAdapter.filter(searchQuery);
    TextView searchText = mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    //searchText.setText(searchQuery);
    Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
    searchText.setTypeface(customFont);
    try {
    ThaanaUtils.thaanafyTextViewSubclass(searchText, "fonts/faruma.ttf");
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    searchText.addTextChangedListener(new ThaanaTextWatcher());

    View xIcon = ((View) mSearchView.findViewById(R.id.search_plate));
    xIcon.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                SearchActivity.this.myAdapter.filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            }
        });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_favorites) {
        //Intent newActivity = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,FavoritesActivity.class);
        //startActivity(newActivity);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    finish();
}



@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

But I don't want to show searchview collapsing when pressed back button. I want to go back to previous activity without collapsing searchview.
How can I achieve that?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: @MohammadMkeinGolchin Check out my updated question with code

Comment: What do you mean 'collapsing searchview'?

Comment: Activity starts with expanded searchview. So when I press back button searchview gets closed and goes back to previous activity. I just want to do this, when pressed back button go straight back to previous activity while searchview is in expanded view. Don't you get it?

Comment: It's a little obscure

Answer (score 0):

Override the onBackPressed() method in your activity and then put your activity redirection code inside the method. This will solve your problem. Happy coding!

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // enter your activity redirection code here.
}
```

If you didn't call finish() on your previous activity, then just call finish() inside the onBackPressed method. This will destroy the current activity(search activity) and will load previous one. Else you need to go through the usual way by declaring an intent.

Comment: No. This didn't help. Still it is first collapsing and going back to previous activity. See my code above. I have updated question with code.

Comment: can you share any screen shot to show how it collapsing?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/hc7fg01z3zq9vcc/InShot_20200324_102642535.mp4/file

Comment: Please take a look at the video. Its slow motion of what's happening.